# Converting the date returned from mongo to this format 2015-10-25

Tags: java, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have a json file returned from mongo db as follow:

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "$date": "2014-10-19T04:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "value": 29
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$date": "2014-10-20T04:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "value": 20
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$date": "2014-10-21T04:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "value": 21
}
]
```

Now I want to read the date in java in the following format: 2014/10/25

but when I use:

```
System.out.println("DAte is : "+result.get("_id").toString() );
```

the result is :

```
DAte is : Sun Oct 19 01:00:00 ADT 2014
```

Then only thing that comes to my mind is to use substring and manually convert the date to 2014-10-25 but I am sure there would better way. Does any one have any idea?

Update :

Here is the answer :

[converting date from one format to another does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805732/converting-date-from-one-format-to-another-does-not-work)

thanks a lot for helping

Comment: The date returned by MongoDB is an `ISODate`, please see the linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use the `DateTimeFormatter`? Then you can parse your dates this way:

```
// The test string
String str = "Sun Oct 19 01:00:00 ADT 2014";

// Formatter for the input date
final DateTimeFormatter inputFormat = 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

// The parsed date
final ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(str, inputFormat);

// The output format(s). Specify the one you need
final DateTimeFormatter outputFormat1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
final DateTimeFormatter outputFormat2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

// Print
System.out.println(outputFormat1.format(parsed)); // -> 2014/10/19
System.out.println(outputFormat2.format(parsed)); // -> 2014-10-19
```

This [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html) provides some good reading for how to parse and format dates. The class `DateTimeFormatter` is available for Java 8, if you are using older versions of Java the class `SimpleDateFormat` may be used instead (it uses a similar strategy for handling dates but is unfortunately not thread-safe).

**Edit:** Updated the formatter after input from the OP

Comment: when I use this line final LocalDateTime parsed = LocalDateTime.parse(result.get("_id").toString() , inputFormat);i get the following error: Text 'Sun Oct 19 01:00:00 ADT 2014' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: it seems the json returns the date in the following format :Sun Oct 19 01:00:00 ADT 2014

Comment: Ok, then you can use the following pattern for the inputFormatter: `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`. I was under the impression (from the file you provided) that the input date looked like this: `2014-10-21T04:00:00.000Z`.

Comment: Are u sure that one will work with this Sun Oct 19 01:00:00 ADT 2014, because I get the same error!

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Do you mean this:Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Sun Oct 19 01:00:00 ADT 2014' could not be parsed at index 0
 at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
 at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
 at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)

Comment: Even if I do not use json and use this instead I will get the same error:final LocalDateTime parsed = LocalDateTime.parse("Sun Oct 19 01:00:00 ADT 2014" , inputFormat);

Comment: Then I get this error Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract value: class java.time.LocalDateTime at this line:System.out.println(outputFormat1.format(parsed));

Comment: Why are you using `LocalDateTime` when the date includes a time zone? Wouldn't `ZonedDateTime` be a better choice?

Comment: The answer is here thankd a lot all for helping :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805732/converting-date-from-one-format-to-another-does-not-work

Comment: min API level 26

Answer (score 7):

You can use this method to parse the mongo date format. But in here we are neglecting time zone. So use this if the time zone doesn't matter.

```
private static String convertMongoDate(String val){
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    try {
        String finalStr = outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(val));
        System.out.println(finalStr);
        return finalStr;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with example: 2018-02-06T20:52:04.424Z"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do something like below.

```
SimpleDateFormat original = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sssZ");
SimpleDateFormat output= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String isoFormat = original.format(result.get("_id"));
Date d = original.parse(isoFormat);
String formattedTime = output.format(d);

System.out.println(formattedTime);
```

Comment: The problem is that the date returns from json is as follow :Sun Oct 19 01:00:00 ADT 2014 and exactly at this line I will stuck : Date d = original.parse(result.get("_id"));

Comment: i have updated my answer,which should handle this case can you test this?

Comment: Not working I get this error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'

Comment: @HamedMinaee: You could use new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:sss") instead.