# subtraction in mongo query does not work?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have a collection as follow:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5491d65bf315c2726a19ffe0"),
"tweetID" : NumberLong(535063274220687360),
"tweetText" : "19 RT Toronto @SunNewsNetwork: WATCH: When it comes to taxes, regulations, and economic freedom, is Canada more \"American\" than America? http://t.co/D?",
"retweetCount" : 1,
"source" : "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>",
"Date" : ISODate("2014-11-19T04:00:00.000Z"),
"Added" : ISODate("2014-11-19T04:00:00.000Z"),
"tweetLat" : 0,
"tweetLon" : 0,
"url" : "http://t.co/DH0xj0YBwD ",
"sentiment" : 18,
"quality" : 0.4,
"intensity" : 10,
"happiness" : 0,
"calmness" : 0,
"kindness" : 0,
"sureness" : 0,
"Hashtags" : [ 
    "harp", 
    "nknkn"
],
"authorID" : NumberLong(49067869),
"authorName" : "Fran Walker",
"authorFollowers" : 93,
"authorFollowing" : 133,
"authorFavourites" : 50,
"authorTweets" : 13667,
"authorVerified" : false,
"screenName" : "snickeringcrow",
"profileImageURL" : "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2180546952/smilinkitty.asp_-_Copy_normal.jpg",
"profileLocation" : "",
"timezone" : "Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
"gender" : "M",
"Entities" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 6,
        "name" : "Harper, Stephen",
        "frequency" : 0,
        "partyId" : 6
    }
],
"Topics" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 8,
        "name" : "Employment",
        "frequency" : 1,
        "Subtopics" : [ 
            {
                "id" : 34,
                "name" : "Economic",
                "frequency" : 1
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 11,
        "name" : "Economy",
        "frequency" : 1,
        "Subtopics" : [ 
            {
                "id" : 43,
                "name" : "Economic",
                "frequency" : 1
            }
        ]
    }
   ]
  }
```

And I am trying to get group by date and get the sum of sentiment for each group divided by (number of item in each group -1). As you see because of that -1 I can not use avg function of mongo so I have to do it manually as follow:

```
DBCollection collectionG;
    collectionG = db.getCollection("TweetCachedCollection");
    ArrayList<EntityEpochData> results = new ArrayList<EntityEpochData>();
    List<DBObject> stages = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
    ArrayList<DBObject> andArray = null;
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$Added");
    groupFields.put("value",
            new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$" + sType.toLowerCase()));
    groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));

    DBObject groupBy = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
    stages.add(groupBy);
    DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
    project.put("count", new BasicDBObject("$subtract", new Object[] {
            "$count", 1 }));
    project.put("value", new BasicDBObject("$divide", new Object[] {
            "$value", "$count" }));
    project.put("Date", "$_id");
    stages.add(new BasicDBObject("$project", project));

    DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("Date", 1));
    stages.add(sort);
    AggregationOutput output = collectionG.aggregate(stages);
```

Now everything works properly except :

lets say the count is 3 but if I add it I expect the number for count be 2 and it is after subtraction but  when it comes to the next line which is devision still count refers to 3.

For more explanation if for example sum is 6  and count 3 I want sum/(count-1) return 2 but it returns 3!!!!
so it seems that this line returns 2:

```
project.put("count",new BasicDBObject("$subtract", new Object[] {"$count", 1 }));
```

but the next line still divide 6 by 3 instead of 2:

```
project.put("value", new BasicDBObject("$divide", new Object[] {
            "$value", "$count" }));
```

it seems that the count in the last line still refers to the old value of count instead of updated one...

Can anyone help me ?

Update:

I myself think if I satge the subtraction first and then do the division it works but I do not know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a slight modification to your `$project` object. You need to make use of the Object that was obtained on subtracting `1` from `count`, rather than using the previous value of `count`.

```
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
DBObject countAfterSubtraction = new BasicDBObject("$subtract", 
                                     new Object[] {"$count", 1});
DBObject value = new BasicDBObject("$divide", 
                            new Object[] {"$value",countAfterSubtraction});
project.put("value", value);
project.put("Date", "$_id");
stages.add(new BasicDBObject("$project", project));
```

The above code would work for groups that have `records >= 2`. If there is a single group with only one record, the count after subtraction would be zero, resulting in a **divide by zero** error.

So you could modify your code, to include a [**$cond**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), to check if the count after subtraction is `0`, if it is, then default it to `1`, else keep the subtracted value of `count`.

```
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
DBObject countAfterSubtraction = new BasicDBObject("$subtract", 
                                       new Object[] {"$count", 1});
DBObject eq  = new BasicDBObject("$eq",
                        new Object[]{countAfterSubtraction,0});
DBObject cond = new BasicDBObject("$cond",
                         new Object[]{eq,1,countAfterSubtraction});
DBObject value = new BasicDBObject("$divide", 
                                new Object[] {"$value",cond});
project.put("value", value);
project.put("Date", "$_id");
stages.add(new BasicDBObject("$project", project));
```

Comment: You are the master of MongoDB :)

Comment: Yes, bat is one the bests ;)

Comment: @Disposer - Please don't embarrass me friend :) .. Happy to learn from you too.

Comment: @HamedMinaee - I am just a learner like you. Just that i get more time to look into the docs :)

Comment: @BatScream Hi BatScream Can you please take a look at this post as well?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554130/inserting-image-into-mongo-from-java-result-in-a-strange-error