# inserting image into mongo from java result in a strange error

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have the following code for saving image in mongodb:

```
    public static void insertImage() throws Exception {
    String newFileName = "mkyong-java-image";
    File imageFile = new File("c:\\JavaWebHosting.png");
    GridFS gfsPhoto = new GridFS(db, "photo");
    GridFSInputFile gfsFile = gfsPhoto.createFile(imageFile);
    gfsFile.setFilename(newFileName);
    gfsFile.save();
}
```

And I got this from this link:

[link for code](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-save-image-example/)

But when I use that I get the following error and I do not know how to fix it ... Can anyone help?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFS.<init>(GridFS.java:97)
```

for more explanation the error is at exactly this line:

```
GridFS gfsPhoto = new GridFS(db, "photo");
```

Update:
Here is the code for creating db connection

```
     public static DB getDBConnection() {

    // If it's not connected to the database, make connection
    if (db == null) {
        initialize();
        makeConnections();
    }

    return db;
}


private static void makeConnections() {
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(dbUser, dbName, dbPass.toCharArray());
    MongoClient mongoClient;

    try {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(dbHost, Integer.parseInt(dbPort)), Arrays.asList(credential));
        db = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Update:

```
String newFileName = "mkyong-java-image";
    File imageFile = new File("D:/1.jpg");
    db = MongoDB.getDBConnection();
    collection = db.getCollection("test");

    // create a "photo" namespace
    GridFS gfsPhoto = new GridFS(db, "photo");

    // get image file from local drive
    GridFSInputFile gfsFile = gfsPhoto.createFile(imageFile);

    // set a new filename for identify purpose
    gfsFile.setFilename(newFileName);

    // save the image file into mongoDB
    gfsFile.save();

    // print the result
    DBCursor cursor = gfsPhoto.getFileList();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }

    // get image file by it's filename
    GridFSDBFile imageForOutput = gfsPhoto.findOne(newFileName);

    // save it into a new image file
    imageForOutput.writeTo("D:\\JavaWebHostingNew.jpg");

    // remove the image file from mongoDB
    // gfsPhoto.remove(gfsPhoto.findOne(newFileName));

    System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: I make it in constructor as follow:public test() {

  this.db = MongoDB.getDBConnection();
  this.collection = db.getCollection("test");
 }

Comment: `db` is `null` when you pass it to the `GridFS` constructor. That is why you get a null pointer exception. The code at the line is :  `_filesCollection = _db.getCollection( _bucketName + ".files" );`. Can you please edit your question to show more code where you create the db object?

Comment: @BatScream thank you I updated, I use this and I can connect and extract info fro mongo but when it comes to image I get this problem

Comment: Can you make sure you are calling the function that creates the database connection before you create a `GridFS` object?

Comment: @BatScream Yes You are right :) Now I put the getConnection inside the function and I do not get that error anymore but when I check test collection nothing in inserted and there is no image what is wrong with that?

Comment: @BatScream I updated the code which is working perfectly , now I am able to insert and retrieve image in java but the problem is when I use db.test.findOne() in mongo nothing returns though I can see in my java console that sth is returned as a image and I evn can save he retrived one... Do you have any idea(I put the most updated version of code above)?

Comment: @BatScream I think I am not using the right command for seeing image in db I also used db.test.files("mkyong-java-image") but nothing returned

Comment: We can chat here, if it still is not resolved: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70508/mongodb

Comment: But ideally you should be querying the `fs.chunks`, rather than the `test` collection. Please read here for more information on how to get a file from the `GridFS` collections - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs-index

Comment: Thanks a lot I wish you could put the above answer as a seperate post then I could accept it You helped me a lot like ever

Comment: Thanks a lot, so when I inser the image I can not have a control to insert in my test collecotion .  I wish you could put the above answer as a seperate post then I could accept it You helped me a lot like ever